# ajax call, check a div in the return for a value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a load more button and the call on click looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pageIndex = 1;
    $('#loadmorebuilds-div').click(function() {
        $('#buildcontainer').imagesLoaded( function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/loadmorebuilds.php?type=trending&pageIndex=' + pageIndex,
           success: function(html) {
              var el = jQuery(html);
              jQuery("#buildcontainer").append(el).masonry( 'reload' );
              $("#loadmorebuilds-div").stop().fadeOut();
              pageIndex++;
              $("#buildcontainer").masonry()

              rowCount = el.find('#countvar').length;
              if (rowCount <= 7) {
                $("#loadmorebuilds-div").remove();
              }
           }

        });

    });

});
});
```

The loadmore.php selects rows from the database with a limit of 8. I do a rowcount of the results to check how many there are being sent back and echo these (for testing) and i can see it correctly e.g. 8,8, and then 5 when there is only 5 results etc.

As well the database results being echoed out into how i want them presented, i also output a div with the rowcount e.g.

```
<div id='countvar'><?php echo $ammountofresults ?></div>
```

As you can see i want to try and remove the loadmore button from the DOM if the div 'countvar' has a value of 7 or less.

```
rowCount = el.find('#countvar').length;
if (rowCount <= 7) {
   $("#loadmorebuilds-div").remove();
}
```

But no matter how many results the div is always removed. I could set the rowCount >= 1 and it will still remove the loadmore button even if the countvar div contains '8'.

Any help on this?

Comment: Apart from all others, If you have constructed your html correctly then `el.find('#countvar').length` will always return either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

In JS the .length() returns the number of characters there are in the object. Example:

```
<div>1111</div> - Will return always 4.
```

Instead of

```
rowCount = el.find('#countvar').length;
if (rowCount <= 7) {
   $("#loadmorebuilds-div").remove();
}
```

try

```
rowCount = $("#countvar").html(); /* Will return the code inside that object, or the num rows*/
if (rowCount <= 7) {
   $("#loadmorebuilds-div").remove();
}
```

Comment: i see, i was instructed to use .length but i understand that now. However even if the result is less than 7 it doesn't do anything now. Seeing as .length works i could try a hacky solution by setting the field empty or giving it a value in the php side and then use .length

Comment: scratch that. Doesnt seem to work. Must be something else and not to with the selecter. Ill go back and check everything

Comment: If it doesn't work then try $("#loadmorebuilds-div").css("display", "none"); Also make sure that the PHP script returns the exact value (Open in the the browser to see)

Comment: if i simple do: rowCount = $("#countvar").html(); alert(rowCount); then that returns what is in the div. However as soon as i do a check so if do: if (rowCount = 3) { alert(rowCount); } then even if the rowCount isnt 3, it will alert 3... is there for some reason the var is being set as 3 in the check?

Comment: OK, finally got something that works. If i remove the number check and just do a if (rowCount) then it all works out so ill just make sure the div im checking is either empty or not.